# Postgresql is giving me a PHP error

Tags: php, postgresql

Error: "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option."

I installed php through yum, can someone give me a step by step on how to fix this?  I'm way out of my comfort zone.

Linux install is Fedora

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install the Postgres module for PHP via yum, should be something like `php-pgsql`.